# wsgi error during django web server setup on Windows 8

Tags: python, django, windows, deployment, mod-wsgi

I have spend days trying to setup a django web server on Windows 8.1. Everything is installed correctly. `wsgi` with the correct version, apache Windows with update and Python 3.6 when I try to Access apache log it shows me this error:

```
[Tue Feb 19 15:40:53.622597 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 4716:tid 1104] [client 192.168.1.229:50746] mod_wsgi (pid=4716): Failed to exec Python script file 'C:/uno/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Feb 19 15:40:53.622597 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 4716:tid 1104] [client 192.168.1.229:50746] mod_wsgi (pid=4716): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/uno/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Feb 19 15:40:53.623600 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 4716:tid 1104] [client 192.168.1.229:50746] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Tue Feb 19 15:40:53.623600 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 4716:tid 1104] [client 192.168.1.229:50746]   File "C:/uno/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>\r
[Tue Feb 19 15:40:53.623600 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 4716:tid 1104] [client 192.168.1.229:50746]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application\r
[Tue Feb 19 15:40:53.623600 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 4716:tid 1104] [client 192.168.1.229:50746] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'\r
```

My virtualenv is called uno and the Project is called proyecto. I do not know why this is happening. I have another machine and it works fine with this configuration.

httpd.conf

```
LoadFile "c:/users/srv/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/srv/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/srv/appdata/local/programs/python/python36"

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:\uno\proyecto\proyecto\wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:\uno\proyecto"

<Directory "C:\uno\proyecto">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'` did you install Django?

Comment: yes I made pip install django and inside .\scripts there is django-admin.exe and .py